# Next Js with Supabase Failed to compile

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase

I created a project with Next.js and Supabase, and everything was running smoothly. However, after adding a table and generating TypeScript Definitions from the PostgreSQL schema using Supabase CLI, I encountered an issue when running the "npm run build" command with the following error message:

```
./src/lib/database.types.ts
Error: Parsing error: File appears to be binary.

info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
```

Do you have any suggestions or steps I can take to address this issue? I appreciate your help.

I have tried with this command:
npx supabase gen types typescript --project-id my-project-id > src/lib/database.types.ts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding the file to my `.eslintignore` file.
In my case it is located in `lib/database.types.ts`

This tells eslint to ignore the file during validation.

I'm not sure if the Supabase CLI generates it incorrectly, but generated files can be an issue for eslint validation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the file encoding that was wrong. Here are three suggested solutions for Windows (you only need to pick one of them).

**Manual solution:**

Open database.types.ts in Notepad. Choose Save As and set the encoding to UTF-8 and then press save.

**Command line solution, one-liner (PowerShell):**

After I posted my solutions, I realized that you of course can do the next suggested solution with one line:

```
npx supabase gen types typescript --project-id replacewithyourprojectid | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 .\src\lib\database.types.ts
```

**Command line solution, several steps (PowerShell):**

Generate the types and store it in a temporary file.

```
npx supabase gen types typescript --project-id replacewithyourprojectid > .\src\lib\temporary-db.ts
```

Encode the temporary file contents to UTF-8 and store it in the actual file.

```
Get-Content .\src\lib\temporary-db.ts | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 .\src\lib\database.types.ts
```

Remove the temporary file

```
rm .\src\lib\temporary-db.ts
```